# HTAccess shorthand redirect of multiple image files with image count in filename?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I was trying to find a shorthand way to catch a number of image cliks from the old domain:

```
http://www.old-domain.com/images/real-estate-nn.jpg to
http://www.new-domain.com/plot/images/real-estate-nn.jpg
```

**nn = 01 to 29**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^real-estate-([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/plot/images/real-estate-$1.jpg [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your condition demands the request URI _starts with_ `real-estate-` … // Why are you even using a RewriteCond here to begin with, the path component can be matched by the RewriteRule itself.

Comment: It was a starting point to try and undrstand how to make it work, and by the sounds of it, it's wrong. Thank you.